# If X is independent to Y and Z, does it imply that X is independent to YZ ?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

After years of mathematics, I am struggling with this simple question.

If we have 3 r.v. $X,Y,Z$ and we have $X$ independent to $Y$ and to $Z$, then do we have that $X$ is also independent to $YZ$ ?

At first sight, I thought that if $X$ is independent to $Y$ and $Z$, it is also independent to the sigma-algebra generated by $Y$ and to $Z$ and hence $YZ$ but the example below made me confused : 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_independence

If someone can make this clear...
Thank you very much in advance !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Short answer: No, $X \perp Y , X \perp Z$ doesn't imply $X \perp YZ$**

Let's say you do an experiment where you choose a number randomly from:

{1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9}

Let X = 1 if:

(Your chosen number is even AND less than five) OR (your chosen number is odd AND greater than 5)

and 0 otherwise

Let Y = 1 if your chosen number is even, 0 otherwise
Let Z = 1 if your chosen number is greater than 5, 0 otherwise

Now we know X = 1 with probability - 0.5 (2,4,7,9) and 0 with probability 0.5 (1,3,6,8)

If we know Y = 1, X is still 1 with p = 0.5 (2,4) and 0 with p = 0.5 (6,8)
If we know Y = 0, X is still 1 with p = 0.5 (7,9) and 0 with p = 0.5 (1,3)

If we know Z = 1, X is still 1 with p = 0.5 (7,9) and 0 with p = 0.5 (6,8)
If we know Z = 0, X is still 1 with p = 0.5 (2,4) and 0 with p = 0.5 (1,3)

So X is independent of Y and X is independent of Z.

But knowing if a number is even AND knowing if it's greater than 5 (Y & Z), makes us know X with certainty. e.g. Y = 1, Z = 1, then YZ = 1, X has to be 0 with probability 1 (as X is 0 if the number is an even number > 5)

$P(X = 0 | Y ) = P(X = 0) = 0.5$ (same for X = 1)

$P(X = 0 | Z ) = P(X = 0) = 0.5$ (same for X = 1)

But

$P(X = 0 | YZ = 1) = 1 \neq P(X=0) $  (similar for X = 1)

Comment: This answer might be improved by showing the explicit calculation: $P(X=0|YZ)=P(X=0)$, etc. Definitely a cool simple example!

Comment: @jdods agreed. I've edited the last part of my answer. Will add more calculation as I get time

Comment: Thanks @sanketalekar This is a great example :)

Comment: I have for $(X,YZ)\in\{(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)\}$ and that $f_{X,YZ}=1/2, 0, 1/4, 1/4$, and $f_{X}\cdot f_{YZ}=3/8, 1/8, 3/8, 1/8$, respectively. So definitely not independent.

Comment: @Wiles01 I'm glad it helped. One thing that will help you construct more examples is that in this case Y and Z individually cut X's probability space in half but maintain expected value. Y & Z narrow down X to a certainty. So Y & Z cut X in different dimensions (evenness and "greater than 5"-ness if you will)

Comment: @jdods I don't understand. How is (1,1) possible ? If YZ = 1, X has to be 0.

Comment: My mistake: I had the variable values mixed up. The corrected numbers should be $f_{X,YZ}=1/4,1/4,1/2,0$.

Answer (score 8):

You can see it as having information on $Y$ is not enough to determine $X$ an identically with information on $Z$ however if you have combined informations it could determined $X$.

An example I came up with is (may be not a good one but it helps me understand whats going on).

You have a set of peoples on with you can know the colours of the hair, given by the variable $X$, there first name given by $Y$, and there last name given by $Z$.

The independence of $X$ and $Y$ tells you that even if you know there first name that does not help you in knowing the colours of there hairs. Intuitively it says that the color of the hair does not depend on your name.

The same with the last name.

However if you know both the first name and last name you know which person it is exactly hence you know the color of its hairs.

I hope this example is not confusing you :S

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I get your point but this means that X could be dependent to YZ. However, the answer of @Andres Mejia seems to indicate we are independent to the "YZ-plane"... So still confused :(

Comment: @Wiles01 Sorry I do not see Andres Mejia answers and I dont know what you mean by: :are independent to the YZ-plane" ...

Comment: I was unclear by was meant by $YZ$.

Comment: Both of you agree that we may find examples where X is independent to Y and Z but X is some way dependent to YZ ?

Comment: and since, it can happen that from $YZ$ we can deduce $(Y,Z)$ it proves that $X$ can be dependent of $YZ$

Comment: is that possible to find a simple example to illustrate that fact ?

Comment: @Wiles01 The example in the wikipedia page is pretty simple. I can rewrite it to fit my example if that help you.

Comment: Thanks @wece ! This is maybe a detail but in the (wikipedia) example, they showed that X=Y+Z (modulo 2). I would like to find some simple example where we clearly see a dependence between X and YZ.

Comment: I don't really see the problem. If you like you can say that $X=0$ means blond hair, $X=1$ black hair. $Y=0$ first name john $Y=1$ william. $Z=0$ means last name smith $Z=1$ means last name jhonson. With that you hide the dependance $x=y+z mod 2$. It only remain that given a full name you know the colour of the hair.

Comment: Thanks @wece ! Coming back to my question, it means that if X is independent Y and Z, then X is not necessarily independent to the sigma-algebra generated by Y and Z ?

Comment: @wece your example doesn't necessarily work, because knowing Y you do know something about X. Agreed knowing Y or Z individually will not help you know X with certainity, but it does affect the probability distribution of X if you know Y (or Z). 

Hair color distributions are not necessarily uncorrelated to first names.

Comment: @sanketalekar Indeed. But here I was assuming Y and X to be independent. I don't say that my example is the best one since may be the hair color and the name are not independent, but I think we can assume it is without to much imagination. A concrete example is the one I give in the comment (adapting the example of wikipedia).