# Equivalence of independent increments imply independence of increment of natural filtration

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

currently I am trying to solve the following problem: Let $X$ be a stochastic process on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ with $X_0 = 0$ $P$-a.s. then if $X$ has independent increments, then for $X_t - X_s$ is independent of the (natural) filtration $\mathcal{F}^X_s$ for $t>s$. I know that the question already was partially answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4275401/independent-increments-iff-increments-independent-of-natural-filtration), however I feel that there are quite some details missing and comparing to other solutions I want to apply a montone class argument, instead of an Dynkin system argument.

**Question**:

You can find my try below and I would like to know whether it is correct or not.

Answer (score 1):

**Notation:** If $X$ and $Y$ are independent we write $X \perp Y$.

**What sufficies?**: Take arbitary $t>s$ we want to prove that $X_t-X_s$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}^X_s$, hence it suffices to show that
$$
\sigma(X_t - X_s) \perp \cup_{n \in \mathbb N} \cup_{0 \leq s_1 \leq \dots s_{n-1} \leq s} \quad \sigma(X_{s_1}-X_{s_0},X_{s_2}-X_{s_1},\dots,X_{s} - X_{s_n-1}),
$$
where we used the fact $(*)$ that $\cup_{n \in \mathbb N} \cup_{0 \leq s_1 \leq \dots s_{n-1} \leq s} \sigma(X_{s_1}-X_{s_0},X_{s_2}-X_{s_1},\dots,X_{s} - X_{s_n-1}) = \mathcal{F}^X_s$.

**Auxiliary Result**: From probability theory one knows the following fact: A random variable $Z$ is independent from a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{G}$ if for every bounded random variable $Y$ that is $\mathcal{G}$ measurable one has
$$
E[g(Z) Y] = E[g(Z)] E[Y] \quad \forall g : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R \text{ bounded, Borel}.
$$

**Main Proof:** Fix some arbitary $n \in \mathbb N$ and let $t > s$, since we want to apply a montone class argument, take the following:

1. We choose the following real vector space
   $$
   \mathcal{H} = \{ Z : \Omega \to \mathbb R \mid Z \in \mathcal{F}^X_s \text{ bounded/real-valued and } E[g(X_t-X_s) Z] = E[g(X_t-X_s)] E[Z] \quad \forall g : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R \text{ Borel, bounded} \}.
   $$
   Note that $\mathcal{H}$ contains the constant $1$ function and is closed under bounded monotone convergence.
2. We choose the following auxiliary set
   $$
   \mathcal{M} = \{ \prod^{n}_{k=1} f_k(X_k) \mid n \in \mathbb N, 0 \leq s_1 \leq \dots \leq s_n \leq s, f_k : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R \text{ bounded and Borel} \},
   $$
   which is clearly closed under multiplication. Secondly one has $\sigma(\mathcal{M}) = \mathcal{F}^{X}_s$, indeed the implication of $\sigma(\mathcal{M}) \subseteq \mathcal{F}^{X}_s$ is trivial. For the other direction observe that one has
   $$
   X_u = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( X_u - X_0 \wedge n \right) \vee -n,
   $$
   since for every $n \in \mathbb N$ the RHS is clearly in $\mathcal{M}$ and since the limit of $\mathcal{F}^X_s$ is also $\mathcal{F}^X_s$ measurable, this proves that all elements in $\mathcal{M}$ are indeed $\mathcal{F}^X_s$ measurable. It is left to prove that for an arbitrary element $Z \in \mathcal{M}$ one has that
   $$
   E[X_t - X_s g(Z)] = E[X_t-X_s] E[g(Z)] \quad \forall g : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R \text{ bounded and Borel}.
   $$
   Let $Z \in \mathcal{M}$ be arbitrary then we can write $Z = p(X_{s_1},\dots,X_{s_n})$ where $p \colon \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ is given by $p(x) = \prod^n_{i=1} p_i(x_i)$ where $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n) \in \mathbb R^n$. Also since we want to make use of the independent increments choose a linear transformation $f \colon \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R^d$ such that
   $$
   \left(X_{s_1},\dots,X_{s_n}\right) = f(X_{s_1}-X_{s_0},X_{s_2}-X_{s_1},\dots,X_{s_n}-X_{s_{n-1}}) \quad P\text{-a.s}.
   $$
   Then observe that using the definition of$p$ one has
   $$
   E[g(X_t-X_s) Z] = E[g(X_t-X_s) p(X_{s_1},\dots,X_{s_n})],
   $$
   using the definition of $f$ we have
   $$
   E[g(X_t-X_s) p \circ f(X_{s_1}-X_{s_0},X_{s_2}-X_{s_1},\dots,X_{s_n}-X_{s_{n-1}})],
   $$
   and using the independence of increments assumptions together under some concatenation property we finally get
   $$
   E[g(X_t-X_s)] E[p \circ f(X_{s_1}-X_{s_0},X_{s_2}-X_{s_1},\dots,X_{s_n}-X_{s_{n-1}})] = E[g(X_t-X_s)] E[Z].
   $$
   Hence $Z \in \mathcal{H}$ and applying the monotone class theorem yields that $\mathcal{H}$ contains every bounded $\mathcal{F}^X_s$-measurable function on $\Omega$. Hence we know that
   $$
   \sigma(X_t-X_s) \perp \quad \cup_{0 \leq s_1 \leq \dots s_{n-1} \leq s} \sigma(X_{s_1}-X_{s_0},X_{s_2}-X_{s_1},\dots,X_{s} - X_{s_n-1}),
   $$
   and since $n \in \mathbb N$ was chosen arbitary, then this finishes the proof.