# Expectation of product of iid random variables and function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

Suppose $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ are iid random variables with mean $0$. and let $Y_i=\sum_{k=1}^nX_k -X_i$. Clearly $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are independent. I want to find the expectation for $i \neq j$

$$\mathbb E[X_iX_jf(Y_i)]$$

Since $X_j$ and $Y_i$ are both independent of $X_i$ I was thinking that
$$\mathbb E[X_iX_jf(Y_i)]=\mathbb E[X_i] \mathbb E[f(Y_i)X_j]=0$$
But I came across this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1739052/if-x-is-independent-to-y-and-z-does-it-imply-that-x-is-independent-to-yz) which says that for three random variables $X,Y,Z$ given $X$ is independent to $Y$ and $Z$, does not imply that $X$ is independent to $YZ$. So I guess my arguement is wrong. Is there any way to calculate the expectation of the product?

Comment: This is not a problem in this specific case, because $X_j f(Y_i)$ is a function of all the $X_k$‘s except $X_i$, and by assumption they are jointly independent.